# is it possible to extend UIWebViewDelegate so that delegate can be notified when document.ready rather than window.onload

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I have a UIWebView, I want to do some operations after WebView content load,So I've set the UIWebViewDelegate, listen to the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method, wish when the WebView loaded that I can be notified.

As the url I request has some pictures and a lot of img tags, I found the WebView webViewDidFinishLoad method been called very slow.

in Apple's document it said

```
webViewDidFinishLoad:
Sent after a web view finishes loading a frame.
```

It did not explain what "finishes loading a frame" really is.So I tried modify my webpage, and added some js code in it, then use Charles to add some Throttling configurations so my images could be load very very slow.Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('ready');
});
window.onload = function() {
  alert('load');
};
```

the ready alert shows very quickly, but the load alert shows only after my images was fully loaded, then the delegate method `webviewDidFinishLoad:` method was been called.

It is bad. because my webpages always has some pictures, I don't want to do operations only after my pictures was fully loaded, I also want to know the document was load,so that I can do some operations earlier.

So, is there any ways that I can know the `document.ready` event earlier than UIWebviewDelegate tells me the whole content was load?

Answer (score 0):

You can notify you native code from within the $(document).ready().

In JS you do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      window.location.href = "native:docReady";
});
```

In OC you need to implement the UIWebViewDelegate protocol and implement the method below:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"native:docReady") {
          // do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and is not too late.